# Tic Tac Toe game app doesn`t work

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, tic-tac-toe

I want to make simple Tic Tac Toe.
Now I have this code.
Here I just click one button and it becoming X, and when I have 3 X in a line there comes a Toast displaying "Game over".
I haven't set Os yet.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton[] imageButton = new ImageButton[8];
boolean[] isIt = new boolean[8];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageButton [0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7) ;
    imageButton [1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2) ;
    imageButton [2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3) ;
    imageButton [3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4) ;
    imageButton [4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5) ;
    imageButton [5] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6) ;
    imageButton [6] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10) ;
    imageButton [7] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8) ;
    imageButton [8] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9) ;
    imageButton[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(0);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(1);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(2);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(3);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(4);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(5);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(6);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[7].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(7);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
    imageButton[8].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(8);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
}
public void gunwo(int y)
{
    if(!isIt[y])
    {
        isIt[y] = true;
        imageButton[y].setImageResource(R.drawable.trasfasd);
    }
}

public void checkIt()
{
    if (isIt[0] && isIt[1]&&isIt[2]){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[3]&&isIt[4]&&isIt[5])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[6]&&isIt[7]&&isIt[8])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[0]&&isIt[3]&&isIt[6])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[1]&&isIt[4]&&isIt[7])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[2]&&isIt[5]&&isIt[8])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[6]&&isIt[4]&&isIt[2])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(isIt[0]&&isIt[4]&&isIt[8])
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game Over", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Compiler does not find any bug, but when i open the app in emulator app doesn`t work.

Here is my LogCat:

```
09-24 14:56:27.899 2781-2781/com.holland.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.holland.tictactoe, PID: 2781
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.holland.tictactoe/com.holland.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
                                                                     at com.holland.tictactoe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

.

Comment: Compile time checks are different to runtime exceptions - you have checked and unchecked exceptions.  You should post the relevant stack trace.

Comment: How to do that? Could you sent me the code? I am new in Android Studio.

Comment: what is the error you receive? do you receive an error? your app closes immediatly? describe your issue

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error that you received?

Comment: firegloves. Yes My app closes immediatly.

Comment: Please post your logcat: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: You  might want to check your array bounds. You are defining two arrays that are 8 elements big, but accessing elements 0..8 (i.e. 9 different elements) in each one.

Comment: jonathanrz, i`ve added.

Comment: jcw, i`ve made picture smaller, but still app closes immediatly.

Comment: Because `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` are **9** numbers... so it should be `boolean[9]` and `ImageButton[9]`...

Answer (score 1):

Once you learn to read the logcat, you'll see

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=8
     at com.holland.tictactoe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
```

It tells you all the information needed, really

Since arrays are zero indexed `imageButton [8]` is the **ninth** element of the array.

You only initialized with 8

```
ImageButton[] imageButton = new ImageButton[8];
boolean[] isIt = new boolean[8];
```

It's hard to create a 3x3 board with 8 pieces

Change those to `[9]`, and you really should use a loop here

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageButton.length; i++) {
    final int position = i;
    imageButton[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gunwo(position);
            checkIt();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you VERY VERY much. How could i write 8 instead 9. I am idiot